# Separate list according to duplicate elements

Tags: c#

I have enum with STAR, SUN, MOON (example)

And i have the following list:

```
STAR,
SUN,
SUN,
SUN,
SUN,
SUN,
MOON,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
STAR,
MOON
```

I am looking for a way to produce the following list:

```
STAR,
SUN,
MOON,
STAR,
STAR,
MOON
```

If we have 1-5 elements from the same type we add 1 entry, if we have more than 5 we add number / 5 or 6, if we have 15 moons we add 3 to the new list, if we have 22, we add 4, if we have 30 we add 5 and etc

Comment: Okay, have you done anything so far? You probably want to write a method using an iterator block which reads the initial sequence and emits entries each time it either sees something different, or has reached a count of 5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 implementations, pick the one you prefer.

First (removes items from original list):

```
// usage:
MyFilter(list);

// method:
static void MyFilter(List<MyEnum> list)
{
    int repetitions = 1;
    MyEnum repeatValue = list[0];
    int i = 1;
    while(i < list.Count) {
        MyEnum current = list[i];

        if(current == repeatValue) {
            repetitions++;
            if(repetitions>9 && repetitions%5==0)
                i++;
            else
                list.RemoveAt(i);
        } else {
            repetitions=1;
            repeatValue=current;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Second (builds a new list):

```
// usage:
list = MyFilter(list);

// method:
static List<MyEnum> MyFilter(List<MyEnum> list)
{
    List<MyEnum> result = new List<MyEnum>();

    int repetitions = 0;
    MyEnum? repeatValue = null;
    for(int i=0; i<=list.Count; i++) {
        MyEnum? current = null;
        if(i < list.Count) {
            current = list[i];

            if(repeatValue==null || current==repeatValue) {
                repetitions++;
                repeatValue=current;
                continue;
            }
        }

        if(repetitions <= 5) {
            result.Add(repeatValue.Value);
        } else {
            for(int j=repetitions/5; j>0; j--)
                result.Add(repeatValue.Value);
        }

        repetitions = 1;
        repeatValue = current;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I will use the first one, Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

You need to output value when 1st item is found and skip 2 to 5.  I solved with a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] input = { "STAR",
                                "SUN",
                                "SUN",
                                "SUN",
                                "SUN",
                                "SUN",
                                "MOON",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "STAR",
                                "MOON"
                             };
            Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            List<string> output = new List<string>();

            foreach (string str in input)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(str))
                {
                    int count = dict[str];
                    if ((count % 5) == 0)
                    {
                        output.Add(str);
                    }
                    dict[str] += 1; 
                }
                else
                {
                    dict.Add(str, 0);
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The output is "SUN STAR STAR STAR MOON", which is not what is expected. Also, he is using `enums`, not `strings`.

Comment: Greg : Did you think the operator may of made a mistake in his expected output.  The code works properly.  Did you verify the expected output was correct?

Comment: I tested your code, and the output was wrong. His expected output is right. I'm guessing you misunderstood the problem.